# Alternatives to classify.oclc.org for getting a book's call number?

Tags: databases, library

I need to get the LOC call number of multiple ebooks.

I used to use http://classify.oclc.org/, but now the website doesn't seem to work anymore.

Is there a (freely accessible) platform, database, dataset, or API that allows user to retrieve a LOC call number for a book?

By the way, I have tried using university library catalogues, and the Library of Congress catalog, but, especially with ebooks, the data does not have the LOC call number.

An example of a title is:
Atlas of Male Infertility Microsurgery

Comment: I Google for "classify.oclc.org" and found it. Warning, it's http, not https. My browser says it's not a secure web site.

Comment: @Nobody thx but no that's not the issue.. it was just a typo.. go to http://classify.oclc.org and try typing any title into the search box, and no results appear

Comment: I just tried it.  After finding nothing for a recently-published book, I found this note at the bottom of the page: "The database is current thru June 2022."

Comment: @BobBrown no every title is not available

Comment: @BobBrown you may try an old title.. say this title from 2008: https://www.google.com.sg/books/edition/A_Textbook_of_Clinical_Pharmacology_and/TD59BgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=A+Textbook+of+Clinical+Pharmacology+and+Therapeutics&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @BobBrown still the same problem

Comment: @forgodsakehold I was able to find the LOC call number for *A textbook of clinical pharmacology and therapeutics,* RM301.28 .T49 2008, by going from WorldCat to the University of Georgia library.  That took a certain amount of work, however, and as my answer says, not every book will have an LOC call number assigned.

Comment: @BobBrown yea I know that.. I did try that.. classify.oclc.org used to have call numbers for ebooks as well.. so now I am hoping for an alternative database.. other than the answer you posted, do u have any other suggestions? I was thinking of BL's MARC record database, but that's a huge hassle to access ;( if anyone has better alternatives, pls do let me know

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find my own (print) book, published in August, 2023 in https://www.worldcat.org/, but apparently you need a paid subscription to see the call number. *However,* WorldCat does list libraries that have a book, and you can sometimes find the call number by checking the entry of a particular library.  I found *Atlas of Male Infertility Microsurgery* in WorldCat, but was unable to find a record with a LOC call number. (One of the libraries with this book lists the call number as "R1.")

The Library of Congress no longer attempts to catalog "everything," and unless a copyright registration is submitted, probably doesn't even know about most material, especially self-published material. The cataloging in publication (CIP) data in most books comes from catalogers who either work for publishers or provide a paid service to small publishers and individuals. For that reason, not every publication will even have a LOC call number.

**Update:** I found this note at the MiraCosta College Library's web site: "Keep in mind that only physical items, not electronic ones, will have call numbers."

Answer (score 0):

try librarything.com i don't know how big that database is but I was able to find call #s there